# If $U, V, W$ and m are natural numbers such that $U^m + V^m = W^m$ , then $m$< max$( U , V ,W)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

If $U, V, W$ and m are natural numbers such that $U^m + V^m = W^m$ , then    $m$< max$( U , V ,W)$...How to prove this?

It can easily proved that $m$ $\neq$ max$( U , V ,W)$ and $m$ >  max$( U , V ,W)$ for some $m , U , V , W$.  But how can I prove that it will happen for any choice of $m , U , V , W$.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: For $(U,V,W)=(0,1,1)$ we do not have $m<1$, but I suppose $0$ is not a natural number for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that $0$ is not considered a natural number. If $U$, $V$ and $W$ are natural numbers such that
$$U^m+V^m=W^m,$$
then by Fermat's last theorem $m\leq2$. Hence it suffices to show that there are no solutions to
$$U+V=W\qquad\text{ and }\qquad U^2+V^2=W^2,$$
with $U,V,W\leq1$ and $U,V,W\leq2$, respectively.

Comment: Making use of Fermat's last theorem for a question tagged algebra precalculus seems a bit overkill, especially as this can be solved with basic algebra and calculus.

Comment: @quarague I absolutely agree, and I think your answer is more appropriate. But I saw the opportunity and could not resist :)

Comment: @Servaes: one should not dare assume a thing as preposterous as $0$ not being a natural number; instead, let us preferably use formulations such as ''assume we are dealing with nonzero natural numbers''...

Answer (score 3):

Assume without loss of generality that $U \ge V$. If $U$ and $V$ are both greater than zero, then $W>U$ and in particular $W \ge U+1$. Now assume $m > W$. Can you prove that $W^m \ge (U+1)^m > 2U^m \ge U^m + V^m$?